# checking the request url for ajax validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some ajax code in my page which outputs some dynamic valuable data, how to make that ajax code to output the data only when the request goes from my site , so that it prevents from using those data by third parties. (the validation should be done using php function)

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this on server, use url referrer on server and decide is this request coming from your site or some where else. Then respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to test the $_SERVER variable on the request script side.

So before it returns the data to the ajax request you do a check to make sure the $_SERVER variable contains information showing that the request came from your server.

I think it'll probably be the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] that you'll want to check, or alternatively the 'HTTP_REFERER' might work too.

Basically if they don't match your server information then just return false or a blank string rather than the data requested.